# JCanvas add new event

Tags: jquery, jcanvas

I would like to know if we can add another dynamic event such as click, touchstart etc..

Ex :

```
$('canvas').drawArc({
  layer:true,
  strokeStyle: '#000',
  strokeWidth: 5,
  x: 100, y: 100,
  radius: 50,
  my_event : function(layer)
  {

  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](http://calebevans.me/projects/jcanvas/docs/eventAPI/), the `click` and `touchstart` events are already supported natively in jCanvas. All you need to do is specify `click` and `touchstart` (respectively) as the key names for your callbacks:

```
$('canvas').drawArc({
    layer:true,
    strokeStyle: '#000',
    strokeWidth: 5,
    x: 100, y: 100,
    radius: 50,
    click : function(layer)
    {

    },
    touchstart : function(layer)
    {

    }
});
```